# Python Examples on Udacity Broken?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to go through one of the Machine Learning Courses on Udacity.  This came to an abrupt halt when the first example would not run.  They seem to be asking me to basically copy-paste some code into a web-based source code file of some kind in python.  TheProblem is I do exactly as they say and I get errors when I run it.  I've attached a picture detailing how I copied exactly what I was instructed to copy and still don't achieve what the video-lecturer claims should happen.  I also don't have a strong understanding of Python so i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.  Any light anybody could shine on this would be helpful.  Let me know if i'm not just going crazy here.. or whether I should give up on this broken example and switch to Coursera or something.

[image]

Comment: btw, the "impot" is obviously wrong.  However, I have fixed that and the error becomes

NameError: global name 'features_test' is not defined.

Comment: make sure you have the modules installed which you are trying to "import ".

Comment: The thing is this is a web course and the only instructions were to copy those 4 lines of code under "your code goes here".  This is why I suspect the web service that runs this Python is broken in some way.  I was hoping somebody may have come across something like this.  I guess I will have to try another course that works correctly.

Comment: it's not broken, just 'features_test' variable is not defined. Check the code snippet they provided, it's supposed to be defined or you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not returning anything. The purpose of the classify function is to create and fit a Naive Bayes classifier. The function is then called in studentMain.py. You have the first part correct, you simply need to add `return clf` to your code. Also, the `pred` variable you created is not needed for that function.

Comment: So removing the pred line and returning clf gets the web service to output what the video instruction shows.  This example is simply broken.  The code they instruct you to place in the classify function is not correct.

Comment: Fair enough. Although the instructors say that knowing python is not a requirement for the course there are some assignments that will be much easier if you are familiar with the language.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the spell check for import, we are just trying to return clf,i.e the training result.Below snippet should work.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
return clf
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys I know its a bit late but I found the answer. here's what I did

in ClassifyNB.py

```
def classify(features_train, labels_train):   
    from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
    clf = GaussianNB()
    return clf.fit(features_train,labels_train)
    ###note that the other pred thing causing issues in not needed as it is
```

link to the image i got as the result of that code https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/jNjRfobbZZL4z8x1q7jyKwgOm8-pMNQ2akmIJB7KjmYaNTfponK1ISplFsr36T6I5IfKXE6M3PLUuxkOwQ

Answer (score 0):

*Answer to your problem*

def classify(features_train, labels_train):

```
### import the sklearn module for GaussianNB
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB as gnb

### create classifier
clf= gnb()

### fit the classifier on the training features and labels
model= clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)

### return the fit classifier
return model
```